# Weird render on heroku with rendering templates app/app/views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm having a weird issue.

Locally everything renders fine, and when I fire it up on Heroku I get this error:

```
2011-12-31T06:26:23+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template pages/index, application/index with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:
2011-12-31T06:26:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
2011-12-31T06:26:23+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
```

Why is it blows up with `/app/app/views`? Why would it have two apps in there? I'm not sure what's wrong. It's a pretty basic app. I haven't done anything fancy.

Comment: /app/ is a home dir of application on heroku, so don't worry about it, it is normal

Comment: First check did you commit view to the git repository :)

Comment: I think @Marek hit the nail on the head (and you should put that as an answer so you get credit) :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In my case it was failing due to haml-rails gem being in :assets group. It was not able to render haml files.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure you add the haml-rails gem tu your gemfile

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem is the haml-rails insitde "group :assets do" in Gemfile

Moving gem "haml-rails" to outside of assets group, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after refactoring with RubyMine. I changed the folder name in /views to use capital "Posts" on accident. Changing it to lowercase wasn't enough to fix the problem. I had to change one of the letters, push to heroku, rename the folder correctly, and then push it to heroku again.